# How to search jobs that I've added through Google Cloud Talent Solution API

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-cloud-talent-solution

I'm using Google Talent Solution API to create jobs under some companyName and these seem to be getting added when I'm listing through API yet they nowhere seem to appear on Google search results or Google Job search page.

The location of company & jobs are same to my current location. Is there any visibility issue (though I've added jobs with SHARED_WITH_PUBLIC visibility) or is there any other way to add jobs? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve HTML pages to Google to have your jobs added to their index.

Here are docs on what data to add to a standard HTML page for job ads:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting